# uncaught exception in xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, layout, storyboard

In an iOS native app I am getting following exception .

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named IBNSLayoutConstraint'`

Can anyone please help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the constraint named as ='IBNSLayoutConstraint' in storyboard

For that:

1.Search with constraint name.

2.find the constrain thats not connected with the IBOutlet.

3.remove the constrain.